# Test the add method of repository in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, testing

I have an error when trying to add in a Spring test:

This is my XML Dataset:

```
<dataset>
    <client id="1" name="name1" city="asd" street="asdf" number="20" dateOfBirth="2000-06-06"/>
    <client id="2" name="name2" city="asd" street="asdf" number="30" dateOfBirth="2000-07-07"/>
    <client id="3" name="name3" city="asd" street="asdf" number="40" dateOfBirth="2000-08-08"/>
</dataset>
```

And this is the test function:

```
@Test
    public void add() {
        Address address = new Address("city", "street", 40);
        Client client = Client.builder()
                .name("New")
                .dateOfBirth(LocalDate.of(2000, 9, 9))
                .address(address)
                .build();
        client.setId(4L);
        clientRepository.save(client);
        List<Client> clients = clientRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(4, clients.size());
    }
```

I kept it as basic as possible. By the way, my "findAll()" test works, so it is not a config problem. This is my entity:

```
public class Client extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private String name;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "d/M/yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client",
            cascade ={CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH},
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Rental> rentalSet = new HashSet<>();
```

And I have a really bad error at "clientRepository.save(client);", it says I violate the primary key, but I set it before with 4, which is not in the db.

I should print the error to, if dsomebody can help me, please:

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CLIENT(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into Client (city, number, street, dateOfBirth, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-193]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CLIENT(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into Client (city, number, street, dateOfBirth, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-193]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
.......
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3001)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3501)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CLIENT(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into Client (city, number, street, dateOfBirth, name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23505-193]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
......
```

Answer (score 0):

I supose it's not working cause once you run your test. you have already a row with ID = 4 cause it's not autoIncrement, so when you will run again your test class, it will throw the primary key  violation exception. to avoid that, you can try add this

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

to make sure that your DB is always is reset after each Test method.

Comment: No, I get that error when running the add test isolated. And that Id really is not in the db. That's why is a very bad error

Comment: So the BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD annotation does not help there